# Extend Django User model and show this on admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-users

I use the latest django for an intranet project. Well, I followed the django documentation to extend my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Employee(AbstractUser):
    DEPARTMENTS = (
        ('ARE', 'Area Manager'),
        ('IT', 'IT'),
        ('CAT', 'Category manager'),
        ('CON', 'Controling')
    )
    departement = models.CharField(max_length = 3, verbose_name = "Département", choices = DEPARTMENTS)
```

After that, I rewrited the admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Employee

# Define an inline admin descriptor for Employee model
# which acts a bit like a singleton
class EmployeeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Employee
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Employees'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (EmployeeInline,)

# Re-register UserAdmin
# admin.site.register(User) # return error: django.contrib.admin.sites.NotRegistered: The model User is not registered
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

As you can see on the 3 last line of my admin.py, if I register User model I have an error. If I comment my last lines

```
# Re-register UserAdmin
#admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I haven't my User administration:
[image: Admin site django without user management problem]

Comment: Have you done migrations? `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: you are importing `User` model from wrong place in your admin.py. You need to import it from `myApp.models` but you are importing the default user model

Comment: checkout https://learnbatta.com/blog/using-custom-user-model-in-django-23/

Comment: @VaibhavVishal: If i write admin.site.register(Employee, UserAdmin) I obtain this error:
<class 'employees.admin.EmployeeInline'>: (admin.E202) 'employees.Employee' has no ForeignKey to 'employees.Employee'.

Comment: you don't need an inline, you should have named your custom user model `User` instead of `Employee` to avoid confusion.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Your user model is Employee. So I don't know why you have defined the EmployeeAdmin as an inline. Instead it needs to be the main ModelAdmin, subclassing BaseUserAdmin.

Comment: Did you change your AUTH_USER_MODEL ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your project has a custom model user definition. The advised way to get the user class in this case is using `get_user_model()` from `django.contrib.auth`.

Comment: I must add a owner = models.ForeignKey() into my models Employee ?

Comment: Do you mean adding a field `owner = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model())`? No, don't do that. What I mean is, instead of accessing the class `User`, take a variable called `employee = get_user_model()`, and register that into the admin.